# limit the maximum size of file in ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

Ext4 has a maximum filesystem size of 1EB and maximum filesize of 16TB.

However is it possible to make the maximum filesize smaller at filesystem level ? For example I wouldn't like to allow to create files greater than a specified value (e.g. 1MB). How can this be achieved on ext4 ?

If not ext4 then any other modern filesystem has support for such feature ?

Comment: You can't do that at filesystem level, but you can set limits for shells.  The exact way to do that is system-dependent (on Linux try `man limits`,  `man limits.conf`, or `man pam_limits`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ext4` has a `max_dir_size_kb` mount option to limit the size of *directories*, but no similar option for regular files.

A process however can be prevented from creating a file bigger than a limit using limits as set by `setrlimit()` or the `ulimit` or `limit` builtin of some shells. Most systems will also let you set those limits system-wide, per user.

When a process exceeds that limit, it receives a SIGXFSZ signal. And when it ignores that signal, the operation that would have caused that file size to be exceeded (like a `write()` or `truncate()` system call) fails with a `EFBIG` error.

To move that limit to the file system, one trick you could do is use a *fuse* (file system in user space) file system, where the  user space handler is started with that limit set. `bindfs` is a good candidate for that.

If you run `bindfs dir dir` (that is bind `dir` over itself), with `bindfs` started as (`zsh` syntax):

```
(limit filesize 1M; trap '' XFSZ; bindfs dir dir)
```

Then any attempt to create a file bigger than 1M in that dir will fail. `bindfs` forwards the `EFBIG` error to the process writing the file.

Note that that limit only applies to regular files, that won't stop directories to grow past that limit (for instance by creating a large number of files in them).

Comment: It works, but a file bigger than 1M is still copied, but truncated at 1M. So it clutters the file system with incomplete 1M files... Any idea how to avoid that ? (i.e. how to delete the incomplete files) ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set this at system level.

For Ubuntu edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Add a line like:

```
timb        hard    fsize           10000
```

You can use wildcards as well.

AFAIK this does not work for root unless you add `session required pam_limits.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`.